# Do I have to re-report old conditions on each medical renewal?

Tags: medical

When I first filled out the application for an FAA third-class medical it asked "Have you ever in your life had these conditions?"  I put yes for a few of them, had some tests done, and was issued a standard medical.  So now I am going in for a renewal and it asks me the same question of "Have you ever in your life had these conditions?" Do I need to re-report the old conditions, even if I have not had any new symptoms?  I mean, if you had some medical condition that happened in the past and is now is gone, and you've been approved for a medical certificate, do you have to keep re-reporting that same past condition on every medical certificate renewal for the rest of your life, even if you have no symptoms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes**, you must always report these conditions on [Form 8500-8](https://www.aviationmedicine.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/FAA-Form-8500-8-GG-Edition-APPLICATION-FOR-AIRMAN-MEDICAL-CERTIFICATE.pdf), forever. **But** you can write "PREVIOUSLY REPORTED, NO CHANGE" in the EXPLANATIONS box as explained in the form's instructions (emphasis mine):

> **18. MEDICAL HISTORY** - Each item under this heading must be checked either "yes" or "no." You must answer "yes" for every condition you have ever been diagnosed with, had, or presently have and describe the condition and approximate date in the EXPLANATIONS block.
>
> **If information has been reported on a previous application** for airman medical certificate **and there has been no change** in your condition, **you may note "PREVIOUSLY REPORTED, NO CHANGE"** in the EXPLANATIONS box, **but you must still check "yes" to the condition**. Do not report occasional common illnesses such as colds or sore throats.

I'd also suggest you keep the records of any extra tests previously done. If your medical examiner wants to investigate any of the conditions, the old test results may be enough to satisfy them.

Comment: You can even shorten that up to writing "PRNC". I've been doing that for decades. Never had an AME even bat an eye.